# Paperclip issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I installed paperclip for my rails project and completed the coding part to use it by following a tutorial. But when I used to see the schema of the Item (which contains image as a column), it created four other columns like image_file_name and assigned them respective datatypes. But the column named image did not have any datatype associated with it and remained empty. Where did I miss something. Also I wish to know how the images are stored internally inside paperclip (ex : as strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paperclip migration creates those 4 fields for internal use:

```
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
```

If you're curious about where the file was saved, you can try opening a rails console and accessing the `url` property of the uploaded image. I don't know what the name of the model is that you added the attachment to, but let's say you called it `UploadedImage` and your image attachment is declared like `has_attached_file image`:

```
$ rails c
irb> UploadedImage.last.url
```

This should print out the path for where the image is stored.

There's a section in the paperclip readme that talks about storage: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage

By default, the location is `:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`